# Getting an error connecting web service using SOAPUI

Tags: web-services, soap, xsd, wsdl, soapui

I'm getting the following error every time I run my script using SOAPUI. It says connection refused. Please Help. It seems to me that there's some firewall issue but when I talk to my network people but they don't think it's the firewall.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.rest.panels.request.views.html.HttpHtmlMessageExchangeResponseView.writeHttpBody(HttpHtmlMessageExchangeResponseView.java:211)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.rest.panels.request.views.html.HttpHtmlMessageExchangeResponseView.setEditorContent(HttpHtmlMessageExchangeResponseView.java:190)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.rest.panels.request.views.html.HttpHtmlMessageExchangeResponseView.buildContent(HttpHtmlMessageExchangeResponseView.java:106)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.rest.panels.request.views.html.HttpHtmlMessageExchangeResponseView.getComponent(HttpHtmlMessageExchangeResponseView.java:66)
at com.eviware.soapui.support.editor.Editor.addEditorView(Editor.java:83)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.components.ResponseMessageXmlEditor.<init>(ResponseMessageXmlEditor.java:49)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.MessageExchangeResponseMessageEditor.<init>(MessageExchangeResponseMessageEditor.java:33)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.MessageExchangeResponseMessageEditor.<init>(MessageExchangeResponseMessageEditor.java:28)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.actions.ShowMessageExchangeAction.buildResponseTab(ShowMessageExchangeAction.java:192)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.actions.ShowMessageExchangeAction.buildContent(ShowMessageExchangeAction.java:98)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.actions.ShowMessageExchangeAction.buildFrame(ShowMessageExchangeAction.java:88)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.actions.ShowMessageExchangeAction.actionPerformed(ShowMessageExchangeAction.java:76)
at com.eviware.soapui.support.action.swing.DefaultActionList.performDefaultAction(DefaultActionList.java:107)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.testcase.JTestRunLog$LogListMouseListener.mouseClicked(JTestRunLog.java:228)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What concrete test steps you try to run? If you run groovy script test step, please provide here your code.

Answer (score 17):

[image: Soap UI]

Try disabling the proxy in SOAP-UI, which indicated in the attached screen shot.
Or Give a valid proxy connection under Proxy settings in SOAP UI Global preference.

By disabling the proxy preference SOAP UI may work in offline.

Hope it might solve your issue.

Thanks,
Madhan

Answer (score 0):

Is this servie or your server is password protected?
You can try these things,
Find end point url in ur wsdl (under soap: address location tag), execute it in browser.
Hopefully it will be returning some error, That means this particular webservice or connection is not available. If it is executing succesfully then try to find the logs or error from server for your request and post here.

Thanks,
ambuj

Answer (score 0):

I have got same error with old version of soapUI. when i use SoapUI 5.2.0 it worked.